# Facebook Canvas Application - send updates to members who installed the application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, fbjs

I want to be able to send updates (in news activity) to users who have installed the canvas application - without posting on their wall or sending them Facebook messages.

One way of doing this could be through the application wall - where I post all my application updates. But these updates would only show up in the news activity feed if a user has liked the application wall. So is there a way of auto liking the application wall when someone installs the application?

Or are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to programmatically *like* something. What you may be able to do is ask for their email and then email them when there is news for them.

Alternatively, if you have the publish_stream permission you can send private wall messages to them.

Comment: Privacy settings on a wall post can only be applied to the current user's wall - not on a targetted user's wall. So an app can't post to another user's wall and apply a privacy setting of private to it. I haven't tried this myself, its based on the discussion here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478497/posting-to-a-friends-wall-on-facebook-privately-using-graph-api.

Comment: That's correct, but my suggestion was that since he is updating users of the app, the app will send *status updates* essentially from the user to themselves. I've used this in an app before: the user gets a private message on their wall.