# facebook wallpost to friend list?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I want to wallpost user's friends as user. (and maybe invite)
Is this possible?

if this is possible:

whats the required? how can i this?

[This](http://apps.facebook.com/gunlukburcpaylas) is my facebook application.

Comment: "Access my data any time"
 no, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Read [this](http://facebook-developer.net/2008/02/20/allow-your-users-to-invite-their-friends/) article or use [this](http://faceconn.com/facebook-invite-friends-php) PHP class. It's quite simple:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
       <title>Facebook Invite Friends PHP Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            require_once 'facebook.php';
            require_once 'faceconn/faceconn.php';
            UseGraphAPI();

            $invite1 = new InviteFriends();
            $invite1->SetMainTitle("Main title");
            $invite1->SetContent("This is Facebook invite friends content.");                        
            $invite1->Render();
        ?>    
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're still woried how to post to user's wall, read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) official article

Comment: @Yusufali: answer edited: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Comment: i know wall post but i want to wallpost as Yusuf. i find this but dont working. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478497/posting-to-a-friends-wall-on-facebook-privately-using-graph-api

Comment: @Yusufali: you can post to friend's wall only with users you have permissions from. So if you post to friend's wall, just do it and it will show like autorized person

Comment: publish_stream,offline_access are there enough?

Comment: @Yusufali: publish_stream only. Your code is nice and should work

Comment: working but dont my want. this code send wallpost but i cant see Yusuf Ali Bozkır. shortly same to this: http://paste2.org/p/1566562

Comment: only normal wallpost. but i want to wallpost to my friends wall as Yusuf. but this seem own post.

Comment: @Yusufali: if you're trying it from your account, Berat Berk Çeki  will get wallpost from Yusuf.

Comment: but where is the my name? this wallpost is berat's .

Comment: @Yusufali: this wallpost is from authorized persion. When you change /id/feed to /yourprofileid/feed you'll see that you'Re posting to your own wall from another user

Comment: how? do you write full code? sorry for my problem. i am waiting.

Comment: @Yusufali: Look. If your account is Yusuf and you authorized your application from Yusuf, you'll see wall posts as Yusuf.

Comment: i want to this. look here: http://oi52.tinypic.com/sq43te.jpg im waiting your reply..

Comment: @Yusufali: I'm not here 24/7.You can do this only with Yusuf's permissions. You need to get Yusuf's access token

Comment: how can i access token? and what is access token? im using Authentication.. help me..